# How do I add an application to Firefox's list of known apps?

Tags: firefox

[image: Firefox's list of known apps]

This is Firefox's list of known apps.

How do I add an application in there ?

Answer (score 5):

Click "Browse...".

Comment: The "Browse..." button is not available in Fx 63.0.3 on Linux, nor is `~/.mozilla/<profile>/mimeTypes.rdf`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem with this procedure because I needed to add commandline parameters on the end of the application's file path, e.g *"c:\program files\counterpath\bria.exe" -dial="%1"*

So thanks, Kokbira, for providing the link to http://kb.mozillazine.org/The_associated_helper_application_does_not_exist , which states:

"*Mozilla applications stores file type and helper application associations in the **mimeTypes.rdf** file located in the **profile** folder. Sometimes you might not see an entry for the problematic file type in the Download Actions or Applications list or the listing itself might be completely empty. In such cases, exit the application, open your profile folder and remove (or rename) the **mimeTypes.rdf** file. (Don't delete the "default" mimeTypes.rdf file in the program folder by mistake.) A new copy of the file will be generated when you restart the application. You should then be able to download again without receiving the error but any previously set download actions will be gone.* "

Comment: This appears not to be true any more 10 years later in Firefox 98 (I do not see that file), and I could not find the types in about:config either (though there was some half-way plausible stuff in browser.downloads.*). Can anyone say where the information has got to?

Answer (score 4):

Do as @nik and @jon2512chua, because you cannot add directly an application to the list in Firefox, but only by that way; once you did it for a file extension, the program will stay in that list (called Helper Application).

More info, go there: http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions

If there are some errors when opening with an application on Helper Application list, follow procedures: http://kb.mozillazine.org/The_associated_helper_application_does_not_exist

Comment: I might be ignorant, but what exactly does your answer contribute?

Comment: well, I improved my question after your comment; "it was a draft before it". it is different from others because it informs that after using, for example, Autocad to open a file extension, it will be added to the list for any file I'll open after that.

Comment: That's what the question asked for: How to add an application to the list. I assumed all answers result in exactly that.

Comment: well I thought that way: they simply show the way, but who asked would not understand what happens later and would have some expectations to a better answer to appear. I tried to clarify that using an application to open certain file extension will add that application tho that list to later be chosen to open any kind of files - I think a more complete answer. Do you agree?

Comment: You have improved your answer considerably and made it quite useful (+1) since my first comment by linking to further resources and adding explanations, yes. Still, your specific Autocad example in your comment was answered just as well by the others ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Browse, Open with, Select from the drop down...
If you are confident on the app association, check the "do this automatically.." too.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work for Playlist files *.pls served from the likes of Shoutcast. The playlists are saved to Desktop rather than opening WinAmp. *.pls files do not appear in the list of 'Applications' and 'Browse' is not an option. There needs to be a way to add MIME Types.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: This adds dimension to the OP.